# Chrome extension with dynamically changing "matches" value?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to change the 'matches' value in my Chrome extension's manifest.json file after installation?  Maybe through an options page or something?  I'd like to provide the ability to lock my extension to a domain but the domain will change per user afterwards.

```
"matches": [ "*://*.whatever.com/*" ],
```

I'd like my options page to be able to change this value.  Does anyone know if this is possible or practical?  And if so how might I do it?

Comment: What exactly is the flow of your extension? The answer is "no, but" and the second part depends heavily on it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by flow.  Is it possible to have my extension change my matches value in the manifest file in an options dialog?  Then they would just restart chrome.  Is that best idea to do this if its possible?

Comment: No, that's completely impossible. But depending on how your extension works it may not be needed.

Comment: you can always match all and then decide if you act on the page or not, or even more efficient inject manually whenever needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use an external array to match URLs for content script injection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423290/can-i-use-an-external-array-to-match-urls-for-content-script-injection)