# Can I use an external array to match URLs for content script injection?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm working on a chrome extension where I'd like to inject a content script into a list of urls. Usually I'd use the regular syntax:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

But for the match patterns I'd like to pull the array from a server. Is there a way to programmatically set the "matches" array (from the background.js file for example)?

Comment: You can create an array and populate it using AJAX. Then, use that array name in the 'matches' property?

Comment: Ok, where do I run the AJAX call?

Comment: Can you show the full function that you have? You can create the list of URLs in the same JS file as a string array and use that may be. Need to try this out.

Comment: That's not the issue, I know how to pull an array from a server, but how to I then associate it with the "matches" property in the extension's manifest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot modify your `manifest.json` file from within the extension. What you can do is programmatically inject your content scripts from the background page when the tab's URL matches one of the URLs you've got from the server.

Note that you will need `tabs` and `<all_urls>` permissions.

**background.js**

```
var list_of_URLs; //you populate this array using AJAX, for instance.

populate_list_of_URLs();

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    if (list_of_URLs.indexOf(tab.url) != -1){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,{file:"jquery.js"},function(){
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,{file:"myscript.js"});
        });
    }
});
```